# What is the significance of using: string.split("").reverse().join(")?

Tags: javascript, reverse

I want to say first.  Very beginner. Be kind. However.  I am attempting to reverse a string.  Put a string into a function as an argument and reverse its order.  For example 'hello' should return 'olleh', etc.

I have complete this by doing:

```
function revString(stringArg) {
    return stringArg.split("").reverse().join(");
}
```

However.  By doing it like this:

```
function revString (stringArg) {
    stringArg.split("");
    stringArg.reverse();
    stringArg.join("");
    return stringArg;
}
```

The resulting output for the second function is that reverse() is not a function.  Can someone tell me what the difference here is?

Comment: `.split()` returns an array. In your second snippet you ignore the return values of the functions.

Comment: Is is possible to remedy this by:  someVar = stringArg.reverse();

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `split()` does not split the string *in place*, but instead returns the split string as a new value. In your second function, you do `stringArg.split()`, but since that operation doesn't happen in place, `stringArg` is never mutated. It retains the exact same value and type throughout, which leads to the error you're seeing.

The reason the first function works is because the function calls are applied to the return value of the previous call. In other words:

- `split()` is called on `stringArg`
- `reverse()` is called on the *returned value* of `split()`, which is an array and therefore can be directly reversed
- `join()` is called on the *returned value* of `reverse()`

But in the second function you're calling them all on the exact same variable, `stringArg`, which stays the same throughout. In order for your function to work you need to modify it like so:

```
function revString (stringArg) {
    a = stringArg.split(""); // Array
    b = a.reverse(); // Reversed array
    c = b.join(""); // String
    return c;
}
```

However this, while easier to understand perhaps, is needlessly verbose. I recommend sticking with the original function.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `.reverse()` is used on the output of `.split("")`.

Using `.reverse()` by itself doesn't work because the line before it doesn't directly change it unless you reassign it with `stringArg = stringArg.split("");`. The first line would *return* the array of characters but doesn't change `stringArg` directly.

So:

```
stringArg.split("").reverse().join("");
```

means to `join` all elements within the array whose elements are in `reverse` order based on the `split`ing of the string. In other words, `.reverse()` is used on `stringArg.split("")`, not just `stringArg` and same with `.join("")`: it is applied to `stringArg.split("").reverse()` not just `stringArg`.

Thus the solution would be:

```
function revString2 (stringArg) {
    a = stringArg.split("");
    b = a.reverse();
    c = b.join("");
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example chains the results of previous method call, where `.split()` returns an array as first link in chain.

The second example performs a separate task on the original string at each line, not chained to the first line which returns an array.

`.reverse()` is not a method defined at `String.prototype`, resulting in the error at `stringArg.reverse()` at second line of function call.

Answer (score 0):

`String#split` function doesn't work *in situ* (doesn't mutate the original string). That's why you can't use `Array#reverse` function which can be called only on arrays. You could try to assign the new, received array into a new variable, **then** use `Array#reverse`, which works *in situ* (mutates the original array) and then, return joined array.

```js
function revString(stringArg) {
    let arr = stringArg.split("");
    arr.reverse();
    return arr.join("");
}

console.log(revString('hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

String.split() returns a new value Which is an array of all the characters in str
Array.reverse returns an array with its content reversed
Join returns a string
These functions don't change their values though reverse may, I'm not sure.
Below the stringArgs variable is set to the return value of each function 
Try:

```
function revString ( stringArg ) { 
stringArg=stringArg . split ( "" ); 
stringArg=stringArg . reverse (); 

stringArg=stringArg . join ( "" ); return stringArg ; }
```